# Cannot update a textbox on a form in Access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on an Access DB that sorts and tracks my firm's business contacts. We have a form called "Contact Profile" whereby the user can select a given contact and view all of his information: First Name, Last Name, Company, Title, Email Address, etc.

On the profile, the user can update a contact's information with the "Update Info" button.

Every single field updates just fine--with the exception of Email Address. For example, I can change Joseph Smith, Programmer at Google to Joe Smith, Program Manager at GOOG with no issues.

But if I try to change joesmith@google.com to jsmith@google.com, the change does not save. Code is posted below. Could someone please take a look and let me know if they have any suggestions? Thanks!

```
Private Sub Command61_Click()

Dim strFirstName As String
Dim strLastName As String
Dim strIndustry As String
Dim strCountry As String
Dim strState As String
Dim strCity As String
Dim strCompany As String
Dim strTitle As String
Dim strStatus As String
Dim strPhone As String
Dim strEmail As String
Dim strOwner As String
Dim DateNow As String

'Allow user to leave some fields blank. User must fill in certain fields.

Dim VisEnable

If IsNull(Me.txtFirstName) Then
    MsgBox ("Please add First Name for this Prospect")
    Me.txtFirstName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtLastName) Then
    MsgBox ("Please add Last Name for this Prospect")
    Me.txtLastName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboIndustry) Then
    Me.cboIndustry = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboGeo) Then
    Me.cboGeo = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboInfluence) Then
    Me.cboInfluence = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboSchool) Then
    Me.cboSchool = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboTier) Then
    Me.cboTier = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboCompany) Then
    Me.cboCompany = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtTitle) Then
    Me.txtTitle = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboStatus) Then
    Me.cboStatus = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.cboOwner) Then
    Me.cboOwner = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtPhone) Then
    Me.txtPhone = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtEmail) Then
    MsgBox ("Please add Email for this Prospect")
    Me.txtEmail.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtNotes) Then
    Me.txtNotes = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtInitialProspectEmailSentDate) Then
Me.txtInitialProspectEmailSentDate = ""
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtNextTouchPoint) Then
Me.txtNextTouchPoint = ""
End If

strFirstName = Me.txtFirstName
strLastName = Me.txtLastName
strIndustry = Me.cboIndustry
strCompany = Me.cboCompany
strTitle = Me.txtTitle
strStatus = Me.cboStatus
strPhone = Me.txtPhone
strEmail = Me.txtEmail
strNotes = Me.txtNotes
strOwner = Me.cboOwner
dtEmailSent = Me.txtInitialProspectEmailSentDate
dtNextTouchPoint = Me.txtNextTouchPoint
strRegion = Me.cboGeo
strSoR = Me.cboTier
strInfluence = Me.cboInfluence
strClient = Me.ckClient
strCoworker = Me.ckCoworker
strSchool = Me.cboSchool

strSQL = "Update tblProspect Set FirstName = " & """" & strFirstName & """" & ",LastName = " & """" & strLastName & """" & ",Industry = " & """" & strIndustry & """" & "" & _
",Geography = " & """" & strRegion & """" & ",StrengthofRelationship = " & """" & strSoR & """" & ",School = " & """" & strSchool & """" & ",Company = " & """" & strCompany & """" & "" & _
",Title = " & """" & strTitle & """" & ",Status = " & """" & strStatus & """" & ", InfluenceLevel = " & """" & strInfluence & """" & ", FormerClient = " & strClient & ", FormerCoWorker = " & strCoworker & "" & _
",Email = " & """" & strEmail & """" & ",Phone = " & """" & strPhone & """" & ",ProspectOwner = " & """" & strOwner & """" & ",Notes = " & """" & strNotes & """" & ""


If dtNextTouchPoint <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " ,NextTouchPoint = #" & dtNextTouchPoint & "#"
End If

If dtEmailSent <> "" Then
strSQL = strSQL & " ,LastEmailDate = #" & dtEmailSent & "#"
End If
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE Email = " & """" & strEmail & """" & ""
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True


     Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        Select Case ctl.ControlType
            Case acTextBox, acComboBox, acListBox, acCheckBox
                If ctl.ControlSource = "" Then
                    ctl.Value = Null
                End If
            Case Else
        End Select
    Next ctl


Me.Visible = False
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmProspectAdmin", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

Form_frmProspectProfile.Refresh

Form_frmProspectAdmin.Refresh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It comes out exactly likely I want it to in Debug.Print, but it does not save that way in the contact profile.

```
Debug.Print strSQL
Update tblProspect Set FirstName = "Jon",LastName = "Snow",Industry = "Other",Geography = "",StrengthofRelationship = "",School = "",Company = "",Title = "",Status = "Dead", InfluenceLevel = "", FormerClient = 0, FormerCoWorker = 0,Email = "jsnow@winterfell",Phone = "",ProspectOwner = "",Notes = ""
```

Comment: Something got hosed.  Your VBA code includes `strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE Email = " & """" & strEmail & """" & ""` ... but there is no `WHERE` clause in this `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Debug.Print strSQL
Update tblProspect Set FirstName = "Jon",LastName = "Snow",Industry = "Other",Geography = "",StrengthofRelationship = "",School = "",Company = "",Title = "",Status = "Dead", InfluenceLevel = "", FormerClient = 0, FormerCoWorker = 0,Email = "jsnow@winterfell",Phone = "",ProspectOwner = "",Notes = "" WHERE Email = "jsnow@winterfell"

Comment: ^^ That is it with the WHERE clause